# How to ignore a directory in Developer tools (F12) search panel (Ctrl+Shift+F)?

Tags: devtools

I would like to ignore the directory "node_modules" from the web inspector "Search all files" results. Is there something like "unmapping" sub-folders?

I know there is has a "Regular expression" checkbox, but it only filters the file content, not it's path.

So the question is: How can I permanently ignore a folder from devtools search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devtools > Settings > Workspaces > Excluded Folders > Add (at the right)

**IMPORTANT**: You will need to close and **reopen** the devtool window to make this work.